# How to customize marquee HTML padding & margin in Shopify html box

Tags: html, shopify, padding, margin, marquee

I'm running into issues adjusting the margin and padding for my marquee HTML. I'm inserting this code into an html box on Shopify, which is why I don't have proper body tags..
No matter what I try my marquee text aligns completely at the top of the html box and leaves a small white space beneath the code (I have a background color on my site)

any insight would be super appreciated

here is my marquee code:

```html
<font size="5"><marquee direction="right" scroll-amount="1" bgcolor="f4f0e7" onmouseover="this.stop();" onmouseout="this.start();">
    <ul class="ticker-left">
    <li>Pre-order AW '21 Collection now </li>
</ul>
</marquee></marquee style></font>
```

Comment: no required code or images provided, harder to tell what is the actual problem.

Comment: Please, share some code or images.

Comment: And don't put attributes in the close tag.